# Does URL of service on GCP CloudRun can be aliased?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

Q. Does URL of service on GCP CloudRun can be aliased with static string?

I plan to run my service on CloudRun. The problems are

1. URL generated by CloudRun is not known before service creation
2. My service region does not supported domain mapping on CloudRun

URL is dynamically created like "https://hihihi-sehvxcp7uq-du.a.run.app".

Suppose that there are two services A and B called by A. To A calls B, A must know URL of B. To achieve this, URL of B must be injected into A as configuration at startup time because URL is dynamic. I feel that this behavior leads unnecessary complexity increasing. To run just one line curl command, metadata or configuration has to be fetched.

But if URL can be aliased as static string (like dns or /etc/hosts), unnecessary configurations can be thrown away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot alias the Cloud Run service URL.

Since your deployment region does not support custom domains, your option is an HTTP(S) Load Balancer.

[Setting up a load balancer with Cloud Run (fully managed), App Engine, or Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-https-serverless)